# Transform List<T> to Map with List of Elements (Map<F<T>, List<T>>) Java 7

Tags: java, list, dictionary, guava

I found a way to transform `List<Object> to a Map<Integer, Object>` but I need

```
List<Object> to Map<Integer, List<Object>
```

For example I have class

```
class Movie {
   public int rank;
   public String desc;

   public Movie(int rank, String desc) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.desc = desc;
   }
}
```

And list:

```
    List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    movies.add(new Movie(1, "The Movie 0"));
    movies.add(new Movie(2, "The Movie 1"));
    movies.add(new Movie(2, "The Movie 2"));
```

What I would like to have is a Map of List for each rank..

```
List<Movie> -> Map<Integer (rank), List<Movie>>
```

with Guava I could do simple transformation like that

```
Map<Integer,Movie> mappedMovies = Maps.uniqueIndex(movies, new Function <Movie,Integer> () {
    public Integer apply(Movie from) {
        return from.getRank(); 
}});
```

But not to `Map<Integer, List<Movie>>`

I could find only on post regarding it

[Java: how to transform from List<T> to Map<f1(T), List(f2(T))> without iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354200/java-how-to-transform-from-listt-to-mapf1t-listf2t-without-iterating?rq=1)

However one approach is using Java 8 and second approach for some reason returns `ListMultimap<Integer, String>`

Comment: `ListMultimap<K,V>` is essentially a `Map<K,List<V>>` that manages the creation of lists for you. See http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html#asMap() for information about how to transform it to a normal Map

Answer (score 5):

The second approach you mentioned is what you want. As [Kiskae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1452094/kiskae) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568044/transform-listt-to-map-with-list-of-elements-mapft-listt-java-7#comment58825147_35568044), a "`ListMultimap<K,V>` is essentially a `Map<K,List<V>>` that manages the creation of lists for you."

As such, you can use [`Multimaps.index(Iterable, Function)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) and [`Multimaps.asMap(ListMultimap)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#asMap(com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap)) to get a `Map<F<T>, List<T>>`:

```
ImmutableListMultimap<Integer, Movie> index = Multimaps.index(movies, new Function<Movie, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Movie from) {
        return from.getRank();
    }
});
Map<Integer, List<Movie>> map = Multimaps.asMap(index);
```

Although you can use `Multimaps.asMap(ListMultimap)` it may be easier to use the `Multimap` directly. See the [Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap) section of [NewCollectionTypesExplained · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) for more details.

Comment: Yep, thanks! Appears to work nicely, step I missed was "ListMultimap<K,V> is essentially a Map<K,List<V>>". What about performance, what would be more efficient, this way or just traditional iterator (like Stefan Haustein mentioned in first answer, iterate over the list and add values to a map http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568044/transform-listt-to-map-with-list-of-elements-mapft-listt-java-7/35579317#35579317 ) ?

Comment: @antohoho It depends on how your going to use it but I would say that the object-oriented benefits of using a `Multimap` far outweighs the negligible performance impacts (which may favor one solution for high mutability and favor a different solution for read-only usage, etc.).

Comment: I wouldn't do this on Android because of the code size implications, in particular high static costs of the two anonymous classes). I also don't see how code that's longer than the corresponding traditional loop is supposed to be "cleaner" or more readable, but I guess that's a matter of taste in the end.

Comment: Note: the `Maps.transformValues` step is unnecessary. `ListMultimap.asMap()` is guaranteed to return a `Map<K, List<V>>`, it just can't actually use that return type. So you can either just cast the result or (better) use `Multimaps.asMap(ListMultimap)` which returns `Map<K, List<V>>` so you don't have to do any casting.

Comment: Also note: You don't _have_ to use `Multimaps.index`. If you feel it's preferable you can just create a `ListMultimap` and then just iterate through your list calling `multimap.put(movie.rank, movie)` to get the same effect.

Comment: Thanks @ColinD. I wasn't aware of `Multimaps.asMap(ListMultimap)`. I've updated the code sample to use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way seeems to have your own "add" utility:

```
static void add(Map<Integer,List<Movie>> map, Movie movie) {
  List<Movie> list = map.get(movie.rank);
  if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    map.put(movie.rank, list);
  }
  list.add(movie);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have it this way but would like it more cleaner way